# No One to One $C^1$ mapping of $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My thought is to use the implicit function theorem. First, if $f$ is constant, then it is clearly not one to one. Thus $\exists p=(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\neq 0$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\neq 0$. Assume WLOG $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\neq 0$. Then $\exists U\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $p\in U$ and the level set $\Omega_p:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|f(x,y)=f(p)\}$ is equal to the graph of $y=g(x)$ in $U$ for unique $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Hence, there are infinitely many $(x,y)$ that map to the same value $f(p)$.

Does this look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's very easy to see there's no one-to-one *continuous* map from $\Bbb R^2$ to  $\Bbb R$.

Say $p\ne q$ and $f(p)<f(q)$. Say $f(p)<t<f(q)$. If you consider any path from $p$ to $q$ there must be a point on that path where $f=t$. In particular there are infinitely many points where $f=t$.

Comment: That is much simpler, Thank you! Just out of curiosity though, do you see a flaw in my argument with the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @user124910 Seems fine

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user124910 No problem. Don't forget to click on the little arrow...